# Renew access token for non-current user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I just took over a Facebook PHP project, from another programmer, and I'm trying to fix some problems she encountered. The app is storing users' access tokens in a DB, because we would like to access some of their user data while they are offline.

The problem is, if for example I'm logged in as the current user, and would like to view data of some other app user, i can only do that if i have the correct user access token for the other user. It works, until i try to use an expired access token. I am aware of the different scenarios, where the token will become expired.

However, I would like to renew the user token of another user, who is not logged in at the time.

Is this at all possible, or do I simply have to remove my functionality, when the specific user access token is expired?

Excuse my english, it's been awhile since i've used it. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Check out this page, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending
It shows how to renew an access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to renew a User Token without User interaction. If that would be possible, the whole point of short living Tokens would be void. You can only use Extended User Tokens, they are valid for 60 days. Detailed information about Access Tokens can be found in the following links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you for giving a quick and precise answer. Im new to facebook app developing. Kinda got it threwn at my face, with no experience. I figured that this was the case, so i already started changing the app behaviour accordingly. Just a sidenote: I'm already using extended access tokens.

Comment: welcome to the world of facebook programming then :) - btw, one very important link to check from time to time is the changelog, a lot of questions in here can be answered by reading all the stuff in there: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog